# To calculate sum() two alias named columns - in sql

Tags: sql, sum, alias

To calculate sum() of two temp column names declared in query  - in SQL

`stud` table has only two columns `m1,m2`. total and total1 is given as temp name.

```
select 
   m1, m2, 
   SUM(m1) + SUM(m2) as Total,
   SUM(m1) + SUM(m2) as Total1 
from 
   stud 
group by 
   m1, m2
```

How to calculate `grandtotal` as `sum(total)+sum(total1)` with the column name declared as temp name for the query to execute.

With cte dosn't support duplicate column names?

How to make use of it to support duplicate columnname

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't do it directly - you need to use something like a CTE (Common Table Expression) - like this:

```
;WITH sums AS 
(
   SELECT
      m1, m2, 
      SUM(m1) + SUM(m2) as Total,
      SUM(m1) + SUM(m2) as Total1 
   FROM
      dbo.stud 
   GROUP BY
      m1, m2
)
SELECT 
   m1, m2, 
   total, total1, 
   total+total1 AS 'GrandTotal' 
FROM 
   sums
```

This works in SQL Server 2005 and newer (and also in some other database systems that support CTE's - which is an ANSI standard).

Answer (score -2):

```
select convert(int, first)+ convert(int,second) as total from test1
```

in this first and second is field datatype is `nvarchar` , and if fields are in `integer` then

```
select first+second as total from test1 , test1
```

is table name.