# ORA-00933 Error on Query of 'With' Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running into an `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` error. What I am doing is querying on a table I built from a `With` query. I've been combing through Stack, trying to resolve this issue with every correctly answered question that I could find, but I still run into the error. It's something small and easy to fix I am sure. it's just beyond me at this point. The error occurs on the line with the second select statement:

```
;WITH sums 
     AS (SELECT a.client_number_id                     AS Client_Number_ID, 
                Count(Decode(a.sub_type_code, 'A', 1)) AS Applications, 
                Count(Decode(a.sub_type_code, 'S', 1)) AS License, 
                Count(Decode(a.sub_type_code, 'L', 1)) AS Lease 
         FROM   mta_spatial.mta_acquired_tenure_svw a 
         WHERE  a.tenure_type_description = 'Coal' 
         GROUP  BY a.client_number_id) 
SELECT client_number_id, 
       applications, 
       license, 
       lease, 
       applications + license + lease AS 'GrandTotal' 
FROM   sums;
```

Comment: I cant see anything wrong. So Divide and Conquer. Try the Subquery alone. remove where, leave only one count. Until you get a working query, then go on the other direction and start adding things again.

Comment: Help me solve it when format the query properly with http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: Thanks @Juan Carlos Oropeza. If I were to comment out the select select staement, the with statement 'sums' table works fine. It's only when I try to query the sums table, that I get the error....

Comment: Next question you should include that info. `WITH` work ok alone. problem is on the `SELECT` to reduce the search focus

Answer (score 4):

```
applications + license + lease AS 'GrandTotal'
```

should be

```
applications + license + lease AS "GrandTotal"
```

- quotes are for string
- double quotes for field names.

Comment: Again, thanks @Juan Carlos Oropeza. I tried this sugegstion as well. I still get the same error...

Comment: lol, i tought you try it and work.... did you try remove that line? Again divide and conquer, remove until you found the guilty statement

Comment: I did remove the line. After that, for some reason I tried removing the semicolon before the with statement. Thanks for helping out @Juan Carlos Oropeza!

Answer (score 2):

Enclosing the alias in double quotes would make it case sensitive. In case you wish to make the alias case insensitive, write it without quotes. Oracle treats such cases as upper case by default. Therefore, Grandtotal, GRANDTOTAL,
grandtotal would all return the desired result.

```
applications + license + lease AS GrandTotal
```

Comment: Thanks @I_am_Batman. I tried your suggestion. I am still experiencing the error.

Comment: @Mike : What is that ; doing in the beginning?

Comment: We caught that both at the same time @I_am_Batman. See my posted answer for why I had it there in the beginning. Thanks for noticing that!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their contribution. I solved it when I removed the semicolon before the 'WITH' statement. I borrowed the query from another stack thread

[To calculate sum() two alias named columns - in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932205/to-calculate-sum-two-alias-named-columns-in-sql)

and modified it to my own use. They had used a semicolon, so I didn't think to remove it. I'm not sure why they had that there to begin with. this is my first attempt at using the 'WITH' clause.

Comment: In SQL Server you get an error if the cte is not at the beginning of a statement. So most people put the semicolon there to terminate any previous statement. I don't know about oracle.

Comment: In Oracle, editors behave differently. For e.g. in SQL developer, which is my preferred editor, ; is expected at the end of the statement. If I start a statement with ; without space, like ;select 1 from dual; it would throw unknown command error.  In toad, terminating with ; also gives  error! We are forced to leave blank lines in toad worksheet between queries. Dunno if settings can be changed though.