# Calculate the difference in percentage between two columns with aliases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have this portion of code in T-SQL.

```
CAST(COALESCE(ISNULL(100.0 * (CTEDefinedYear.[Individual Cases]-CTEPreviousYear.[Individual Cases Last Year])
           /NULLIF(CTEDefinedYear.[Individual Cases],0),0),0) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + '%'
           AS 'Defined Year VS Previous Year (Individual)',
CAST(COALESCE(ISNULL(100.0 * (CTEDefinedYear.[Group Cases]-CTEPreviousYear.[Group Cases Last Year])
           /NULLIF(CTEDefinedYear.[Group Cases],0),0),0) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + '%'
           AS 'Defined Year VS Previous Year (Group)'
```

They are two columns, one called 'Defined Year VS Previous Year (Individual)' and the other called 'Defined Year VS Previous Year (Group)'. Both these columns produce a number with a % sign concatenated to it, for example 90 % or 0 %, could be any number.

I want to add another column which will calculate the total difference between the two values in each column. I've found this [To calculate sum() two alias named columns - in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932205/to-calculate-sum-two-alias-named-columns-in-sql) but I don't want to use a CTE. I've also tried this code:

```
CAST(ISNULL([Defined Year VS Previous Year (Individual)] - [Defined Year VS Previous Year (Group)]) * 100
            / [Defined Year VS Previous Year (Individual)])
```

and getting these errors.

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 203
Invalid column name 'Defined Year VS Previous Year (Individual)'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 203
Invalid column name 'Defined Year VS Previous Year (Group)'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 204
Invalid column name 'Defined Year VS Previous Year (Individual)'.
```

I'm not sure what else to do here, I feel like it's something basic but can't seem to get my head round it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is annoying but you need to materialized the calculations (in table, CTE, etc) or copy and paste the calculations expressions (there are no other options and yes, it does not look nice).

The reason of this is the [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement), which is:

[image]

So, we have:

> This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made
>   available to the clauses in subsequent steps. ... because the SELECT
>   clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in
>   that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses. However, they
>   can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as the ORDER BY clause.

As you are defining your aliases in the `SELECT` statement, you are not allowed to use them in the same phase, because they are not yet defined, right?

That's why you cannot use ranking functions (again defined in the `SELECT`) in the `WHERE` clause - when the `WHERE` clause is handled, the ranking functions are not yet evaluated.

And again, I've been there a lot of times - there is nothing you can do. You need to materialized the computation or copy it again.